# Writing bash script for X-11 forwarding

Tags: bash, unix

I was having problem with SSH X-11 forwarding while I used sudo. I found a solution for it.

```
$hostname
server4.a.b.edu
```

First I do:

```
$ echo $DISPLAY
localhost:10.0
```

then

```
$ xauth list
server1.a.b.edu/unix:12  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  6026864294a0e081ac452e8740bcd0fe
server4.a.b.edu/unix:10  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  f01fbfe0c0d68e30b45afe3829b27e58
```

Then I need to do

```
$ sudo xauth add server4.a.b.edu/unix:10  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  f01fbfe0c0d68e30b45afe3829b27e58
```

for sudo to work, for the cookie with my server name and display.

How do I write a bash script to automate this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't need a script at all; it's just a single command.

```
sudo xauth add `xauth list $DISPLAY`
```

Comment: does `xauth list $DISPLAY` give you just the 1 line for your display?  I'm wondering if you have different versions of stuff than I do.

Comment: try `xauth list ${DISPLAY#localhost}` and if that shows something, then use `sudo xauth add $(xauth list ${DISPLAY#localhost})`

Comment: I got `xauth: (argv):1:  bad "add" command line` and `xauth list ${DISPLAY#localhost}` shows nothing, what should I do ?

Answer (score 6):

One thing that worked on RHEL6 was exporting the XAUTHORITY variable before sudoing, for example:

```
export XAUTHORITY=~/.Xauthority
sudo xclock
```

Answer (score 1):

I do

```
sudo su otheruser -c "xauth add $(xauth list :${DISPLAY##*:}); xterm"
```

Replace xterm with the GUI command you want to run

Answer (score 0):

I use this after I've logged in with ssh:

```
echo -n "xauth add `xauth list :${DISPLAY#*:}`" | sudo su - otheruser
sudo su - otheruser
echo -n "xauth remove :${DISPLAY#*:}" | sudo su - otheruser
```

Basically it strips out the hostname part of the display. `xauth` still finds it when used like this.

It works even if you don't have sudo permissions for any other command than "`su - otheruser`". It also removes the added cookie afterwards for increased security and cleanliness. :)

You can replace the `sudo su - otheruser` command in the middle with any sudo command variant you like.